# selecting linq list is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

the select is slow when the I try to include the commented part of the code (5 mins for fetching 21k 
 rows).

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of my code

```
 var q = db.Storages.Where(x => x.LocationID == lngID && x.IsStored == true && x.Item.isInUse == false).ToList();


                if (q.Count() > 0)
                {

                    List<StorageMdl> lst = q.Select(x => new StorageMdl
                    {
                        lngID = x.ID,
                        strItemID = x.ItemID,
                        lngLocationID = x.LocationID,
                        itmMdl = new ItemMdl
                        {
                            strID = x.ID
                            //strBarCode = x.Item.Barcode,
                            //strColor = x.Item.Color,
                            //bolIsInUse = x.Item.isInUse,
                            //bolIsActive = x.Item.isActive,
                            //dteCreateDate = x.Item.CreateDate.Value,
                            //strDisposalRefNo = x.Item.DisposalRefNo,
                            //strCreatedBy = x.Item.CreatedBy,
                            ////dteDisposalDate = x.Item.DisposalDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                            //itMdl = new ItemTypeMdl
                            //{
                            //    lngID = x.Item.ItemType.ID,
                            //    strName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                            //    bolHasBarcode = x.Item.ItemType.hasBarcode,
                            //    bolHasManyColors = x.Item.ItemType.hasManyColor,
                            //    strCreatedBy = x.Item.ItemType.CreatedBy,
                            //    dteCreateDate = x.Item.ItemType.CreateDate.HasValue ? (DateTime)x.Item.ItemType.CreateDate : new DateTime(),
                            //    bolIsActive = x.Item.ItemType.isActive
                            //},
                            //strITName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                            //strManufacturer = x.Item.Manufacturer,
                            //strDescription = x.Item.Description
                        },
                        bolIsStored = x.IsStored.HasValue ? (bool)x.IsStored : false,
                        strStoredBy = x.StoredBy,
                        strApprovedStoreBy = x.ApproveStoreBy,
                        dteStoredDate = x.StoreDate,
                        dteItemOut = x.ItemOutDate.HasValue ? (DateTime)x.ItemOutDate : new DateTime(),
                        strItemOutBy = x.ItemOutApproveBy
                    }).ToList();
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You creating 21000 objects into memory. What is your machine? IMHO try rethink if its necessary. If it is for grid you can use paginator as well.

Comment: What indexes do you have? These will make a huge difference.

Comment: What time does the code need to execute without the commented out code?

Comment: Build as much of your `List<StorageMdl>` as possible from your original query, Don't  first store the query in `q` and then go back in a loop, that's just plain crazy. (Have you any idea how many round trips to the database you're doing? My word.) Just build it right from the beginning. For the values where you're putting in defaults in place of nulls, do that after the fact if necessary. There's no reason it should take 5 minutes to load 21K objects when you load them sensibly (unless your database just isn't up to the task considering its load).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Hi, thank you for your suggestion, maybe I will do it that way. Anyway, I was just wondering because I have a function that uses the same way of selecting, but is much more faster, the only difference is it traverse from _Item_ to _ItemType_, Do you think my problem is related with indexes?

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core? Have you debugged the SQL query or queries?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you retrieve your data (like what database system, ORM and stuff is in action). But from what I see you may have a n+1 problem.

The commented out code does access the `Item` property of your `Storage` object. It also access the `ItemType` property of the `Item` object. Maybe your ORM (or whatever) does lazy loading. That means it issues a db query for every single object you create. That would result in a really bad performance. Maybe you attach some profiler and analyse the actual database queries.

Comment: I also have the same query on my other function, but it only traverse from _Item_  to _ItemType_,and it can fetch 21k rows on a short time. Do you think my issue has something to do with indexes?

Comment: I cant say if thats the problem but having an index over a row that is used for filtering / joining is always a good idea and boosts performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the round trips to the database  your second select to the navigational properties (i.e x.Item or x.Item.ItemType) is making multiple round trips to the database causing the query to be slow .Try running you whole query before calling .toList()

Im not really sure about the null-able types in Storage table but the idea is  :

```
List<StorageMdl> lst = db.Storages.Where(x => x.LocationID == lngID && x.IsStored == true && x.Item.isInUse == false)
                  .Select(x => new StorageMdl
                    {
                        lngID = x.ID,
                        strItemID = x.ItemID,
                        lngLocationID = x.LocationID,
                        itmMdl = new ItemMdl
                        {
                            strID = x.ID
                            strBarCode = x.Item.Barcode,
                            strColor = x.Item.Color,
                            bolIsInUse = x.Item.isInUse,
                            bolIsActive = x.Item.isActive,
                            dteCreateDate = x.Item.CreateDate.Value,
                            strDisposalRefNo = x.Item.DisposalRefNo,
                            strCreatedBy = x.Item.CreatedBy,
                            dteDisposalDate = x.Item.DisposalDate!=null ? x.Item.DisposalDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                            itMdl = new ItemTypeMdl
                            {
                                lngID = x.Item.ItemType.ID,
                                strName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                                bolHasBarcode = x.Item.ItemType.hasBarcode,
                                bolHasManyColors = x.Item.ItemType.hasManyColor,
                                strCreatedBy = x.Item.ItemType.CreatedBy,
                                dteCreateDate = x.Item.ItemType.CreateDate!=null ? x.Item.ItemType.CreateDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                                bolIsActive = x.Item.ItemType.isActive
                            },
                            strITName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                            strManufacturer = x.Item.Manufacturer,
                            strDescription = x.Item.Description
                        },
                        bolIsStored = x.IsStored!=null ? x.IsStored.Value : false,
                        strStoredBy = x.StoredBy,
                        strApprovedStoreBy = x.ApproveStoreBy,
                        dteStoredDate = x.StoreDate,
                        dteItemOut = x.ItemOutDate!=null ? x.ItemOutDate.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
                        strItemOutBy = x.ItemOutApproveBy
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted my previous code to this

```
                if (q.Count() > 0)
                {
                    List<StorageMdl> a = db.Storages.Where(x => x.LocationID == lngID && x.IsStored == true && x.Item.isInUse == false)
                                           .Select(x => new StorageMdl
                                           {
                                               lngID = x.ID,
                                               strItemID = x.ItemID,
                                               lngLocationID = x.LocationID,
                                               itmMdl = new ItemMdl
                                               {
                                                   strID = x.ID,
                                                   strBarCode = x.Item.Barcode,
                                                   strColor = x.Item.Color,
                                                   bolIsInUse = x.Item.isInUse,
                                                   bolIsActive = x.Item.isActive,
                                                   dteCreateDate = x.Item.CreateDate.Value,
                                                   strDisposalRefNo = x.Item.DisposalRefNo,
                                                   strCreatedBy = x.Item.CreatedBy,
                                                   dteDisposalDate = x.Item.DisposalDate,
                                                   itMdl = new ItemTypeMdl
                                                   {
                                                       lngID = x.Item.ItemType.ID,
                                                       strName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                                                       bolHasBarcode = x.Item.ItemType.hasBarcode,
                                                       bolHasManyColors = x.Item.ItemType.hasManyColor,
                                                       strCreatedBy = x.Item.ItemType.CreatedBy,
                                                       dteCreateDate = x.Item.ItemType.CreateDate ?? DateTime.Now,
                                                       bolIsActive = x.Item.ItemType.isActive
                                                   },
                                                   strITName = x.Item.ItemType.Name,
                                                   strManufacturer = x.Item.Manufacturer,
                                                   strDescription = x.Item.Description
                                               },
                                               bolIsStored = x.IsStored ?? false,
                                               strStoredBy = x.StoredBy,
                                               strApprovedStoreBy = x.ApproveStoreBy,
                                               dteStoredDate = x.StoreDate,
                                               dteItemOut = x.ItemOutDate ?? DateTime.Now,
                                               strItemOutBy = x.ItemOutApproveBy
                                           }).ToList();
                    retVal.Add("exitCode", 1);
                    retVal.Add("list", lststored);
                }
```

and it went faster than before.

Thank you for all your help. :)